# Want to create a bar after Action bar in codename1

Tags: codenameone

trying to make an action bar with three buttons after the toolbar and keep it in all my app pages

[image: example screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea...

```
Form hi = new Form("MyToolbar", BoxLayout.y());
Button btn1 = new Button("Button 1");
Button btn2 = new Button("Button 2");
Button btn3 = new Button("Button 3");
hi.getToolbar().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, GridLayout.encloseIn(3, btn1, btn2, btn3));
hi.add(new Label("My Content Pane"));
hi.show();
```

I'm not sure if this is a proper solution or a workaround, because there isn't a specific API. This relies on the fact that `Toolbar` uses a `BorderLayout`.

Comment: You shouldn't change the toolbar container in this way. You can call `setTitleComponent ` for toolbar which is the correct way but here you're implicitly relying on implementation details. Specifically the current layout of the toolbar. 
I wouldn't touch the toolbar, just define a common base class for all the forms in the app.